# If I pull the data from BiqQuery, will Google charge me or not for sending the data to Data Studio?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I pull the data from BiqQuery, will Google charge me or not for sending the data to Data Studio?

Answer (score 1):

That depends.  BigQuery is a consumption based model, unless you purchased slots.  What that means is, any time you query you're utilizing resources and then getting charged at their defined rate, $5 per TB of data scanned.

There are a few caveats to that however one being that the first TB of data scanned per month is free, and not every query issued will scanned data as it may use cache.  If you are concerned about the associated cost one option would be to utilize the BigQuery sandbox.  It has limited functionality but will not charge you, however there are limitations.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-cloud-console

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery runs queries that you pay.

DataStudio runs queries on BigQuery that you pay.

There is no cost of transfer between the two systems.